# Arch Linux doesn't mount two USB drive?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

One is USB modem which is connected and working and problematic one is a plain vfat USB stick which contain data ....that is the fellow not mounting :(

I have tried to see it by fdisk ....it doesn't mount autometically...

Is there any UDEV rule for that?? Because I have put a udev rule to remove the usb-storage thing( I had to.. otherwise the usb modem wont get connected... it waits for storage to relase the port)

Any idea and solution would be greatly appreciated

PS: I am running Arch distribution.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this USB stick is functioning?  Do you have another computer you can plug it into?

Comment: Sorted out mate! take away the usb-storage module was a mistake... so rectify it... seems alright now. Thanks for your time and answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorted out...usb-storage module was not loading.

Comment: Could you please mark this as the answer so it doesn't pop to the top randomly? Thank you!

Comment: Chris I don't know how to do that..could you lead me to that pls?

Comment: click the empty "tick" mark below the answer score